# Python - abs vs fabs

Tags: python

I noticed that in python there are two similar looking methods for finding the absolute value of a number:

First

```
abs(-5)
```

Second

```
import math
math.fabs(-5)
```

How do these methods differ?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

[`math.fabs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.fabs) converts its argument to float if it can (if it can't, it throws an exception). It then takes the absolute value, and returns the result as a float.

In addition to floats, [`abs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs) also works with integers and complex numbers. Its return type depends on the type of its argument.

```
In [7]: type(abs(-2))
Out[7]: int

In [8]: type(abs(-2.0))
Out[8]: float

In [9]: type(abs(3+4j))
Out[9]: float

In [10]: type(math.fabs(-2))
Out[10]: float

In [11]: type(math.fabs(-2.0))
Out[11]: float

In [12]: type(math.fabs(3+4j))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/npe/<ipython-input-12-8368761369da> in <module>()
----> 1 type(math.fabs(3+4j))

TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

Comment: `abs` works with far more than just integers and floats, and the result type is __not__ always the same as the argument, e.g. `abs(3+4j)`.

Comment: add in a comment about `fabs` taking longer due to its always-float nature and you've got the right answer!

Comment: @agf: Thanks for reminding me about complex numbers. Out of interest, what other classes of things can `__builtin__.abs()` be successfully applied to?

Comment: @aix Any user defined class that defines the `__abs__` magic method

Comment: Why would someone use fabs() instead of abs() in Python, where things seem to automatically get converted between int and float as required? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Edit: as @aix suggested, a better (more fair) way to compare the speed difference:

```
In [1]: %timeit abs(5)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 86.5 ns per loop

In [2]: from math import fabs

In [3]: %timeit fabs(5)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 115 ns per loop

In [4]: %timeit abs(-5)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 88.3 ns per loop

In [5]: %timeit fabs(-5)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 114 ns per loop

In [6]: %timeit abs(5.0)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 92.5 ns per loop

In [7]: %timeit fabs(5.0)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 93.2 ns per loop

In [8]: %timeit abs(-5.0)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 91.8 ns per loop

In [9]: %timeit fabs(-5.0)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 91 ns per loop
```

So it seems `abs()` only has slight speed advantage over `fabs()` for integers. For floats, `abs()` and `fabs()` demonstrate similar speed.

---

In addition to what @aix has said, one more thing to consider is the speed difference:

```
In [1]: %timeit abs(-5)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 102 ns per loop

In [2]: import math

In [3]: %timeit math.fabs(-5)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 194 ns per loop
```

So `abs()` is faster than `math.fabs()`.

Comment: You're not comparing apples to apples there. Use `from math import fabs` for sure, and try `-5.0` for both.

Comment: Also unreliable timing results? You first had abs(-5) at 102ns, then later show it as 88.3ns.  Never draw conclusions from a single run of any benchmark, even if it internally tries to avoid the issues as timeit does.

Comment: Two more points: this still compares apples and oranges, since abs is looked up in the builtins, while fabs is at module namespace. Do "xabs = abs" then xabs(num) to remove that effect.  Also, with Python 3.2 things change quite a bit and apparently abs() is quite a bit faster (>2x), at least on floats.

Comment: @PeterHansen You are right, those are from two runs under different system loads. Though when compared within the same set of tests, the relative difference is still valid. Also, thanks for pointing out the namespace difference -- I didn't consider that. I haven't tried it on 3.2, but that's good to know! I will update my answer with your suggestions a bit later :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

`math.fabs()` always returns float, while `abs()` may return integer.

Comment: `abs` may return any type, depending on the `__abs__` special method of the type it's called on.

Answer (score 1):

`abs()` :
 Returns the absolute value as per the argument i.e. if argument is int then it returns int, if argument is float it returns float.
 Also it works on complex variable also i.e. `abs(a+bj)` also works and returns absolute value i.e.`math.sqrt(((a)**2)+((b)**2)`

`math.fabs()` :
 It only works on the integer or float values. Always returns the absolute float value no matter what is the argument type(except for the complex numbers).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `abs()` and `fabs()` is:

**abs():** Calculate the absolute value element-wise. But the element is typed(int) then it will return type(int) and if the argument is typed float it will return typed(float). Simple whatever you passed it will return the same type of data.

> abs() method also work with complex data

***For Example:***

```py
x = np.array([-12,-19,4])
abs_x = np.abs(x) 
print(abs_x)    #output: [12 19 4]
```

**fabs():** Calculate the absolute value element-wise. But this method returns the value always in float.

> So the main difference between `abs()` and `fabs()` is:
>
> `fabs()` always return float and `fabs()` cannot handled complex value.

***For Example:***

```py
x = np.array([-12,-19,4])
abs_x = np.fabs(x) 
print(abs_x)  #output: [12.0 19.0  4.0]
```