# How to compare the last index to the first in a list whilst iterating, or looping

Tags: python-3.x

I want to compare the last index to the first index in a loop or map step. I want something like this using 'map':

```
def difference(angle):
    return angle.next() - angle

angles = [90,180,270]
diff = list(map(difference,angles))
print(diff)
```

Or something like this using a 'for' loop:

```
angles = [90,180,270]
diff = []
for angle in angles:
    diff.append(angles.next()-angle)

print(diff)
```

They don't work. You can't call `.next()` on an int type.

This does work, but it seems very messy:

```
angles = [90,180,270]
i = 0
diff = []
angles.append(angles[0])
while i <len(angles)-1:
    diff.append(angles[i+1]-angles[i])
    i += 1

print(diff)
```

Is there a neater solution? I don't feel like I should have to append the first index to the end to do this operation.

Comment: So you want the difference of every two adjacent list items, but looping around t the end so that the last item is also right before the first item?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, if that wasn't clear. The last piece of code does what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip` to combine the original list and the same list shifted by one item:

```
diff = [left-right for left, right in zip(angles, angles[1:]+angles[:1])]
```

For `angles = [90,180,270]`, the result would be `[-90, -90, 180]`.

---

Or the other way round (subtract the left value from the right one):

```
diff = [right-left for left, right in zip(angles, angles[1:]+angles[:1])]
```

For `angles = [90,180,270]`, the result would be `[90, 90, -180]`.

---

You can also just eliminate the sign using `abs(...)` if you don't want it:

```
diff = [abs(left-right) for left, right in zip(angles, angles[1:]+angles[:1])]
```

For `angles = [90,180,270]`, the result would be `[90, 90, 180]`.

Comment: Yes. That is great. I'm fine with the negative signs, even though my example gives `[90,90,-180]`.

Comment: @Jordan in that case you would simply have to swap `left` and `right`.

Comment: Yeah. That is fine. In my particular case, I am actually using `math.fabs(left-right)`. Or something like that.

Comment: @JordanStewart In *that* case I would use the builtin `abs(...)` instead of `math.fabs(...)`. The first one should be minimally faster and is more flexible. [--> Difference between abs() and math.fabs()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10772302/4464570)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go at this:

```
diff = []
while i <len(angles)-1:
    diff.append(angles[i+1]-angles[i])
    i += 1
diff.append(angles[len(angles)-1]-angles[0])
```